# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. with IDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, idatareader

I have some code that is supposed to connect with a database and populate some fields with existing information that is on the table.

I have run into the Object refrence not set to an instance of an object on the line with my IDataReader

```
IDataReader dr0 = DB.GetRS("SELECT * FROM StorefrontTheme as st 
INNER JOIN Store as str 
ON st.ThemeID = str.ThemeID WHERE CustomerID = '" 
+ Session["CustomerID"].ToString() + "'");
```

If there os any additional information needed I will supply it

Thank you

The Problem was my session variable.. I completely forgot I was no longer using

```
session["CustomerID"]
```

Again thank you

Comment: Check that both `DB` and `Session["CustomerID"]` is non-null.

Comment: It could be your `Session["CustomerID"]` that is null

Comment: Oh wow, I cannot believe I totally missed that... Session["CustomerID"] is currently null 
Thank you, I still cannot believe I look right over that

Comment: look at the following link this will help you to understand how to use a DataReader http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson04.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, by both posters, CustomerID was coming back null